# Obtaining Access Token Using ADAL in an Android Service

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-service, adal

I am developing a Xamarin Android app and I have an Android service that needs to obtain an access token using ADAL. I am able to obtain a token in an Android activity following the sample code [here](https://github.com/azure-samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-multitarget). However, in an Android service, `OnActivityResult` is not defined, which means I need a new way to continue the token acquisition after calling `AcquireTokenAsync`.

Is it possible for an Android service to obtain the token directly by calling the ADAL library? If not, what are some workarounds? I have thought about letting the service start a new Android activity to do the authentication.